# Changes in CvRect values not being reflected in image

Tags: image-processing, opencv

The minimum bounding rectangle of a contour is returned by `OpenCv` as a `CvRect` structure. I'm trying to have an *m* pixel thick margin/border around the sub-image that corresponds to this `CvRect` on the original image, i.e. instead of the exact bounding rectangle of a component(contour) we get something larger containing the component and also its immediately surrounding pixels.

Taking care of the image bounds, I'm using the following code to increase size of the `CvRect` which is later applied with `CvSetImageROI()` to get the sub-image:

```
//making m px border around subimg
CvRect box_swt = box1;
box_swt.x = (box1.x)>m ? box1.x-m : box1.x;
box_swt.y = (box1.y)>m ? box1.y-m : box1.y;
box_swt.width = (box1.x + box1.width) < img->width-m ? box1.width+m : box1.width;
box_swt.height = (box1.y + box1.height) < img->height-m ? box1.height+m : box1.height;
```

Here, `box1` stores the return from `cvBoundingRect(ptr, 0)` where ptr is a pointer to detected contours.

The problem is that the resulting sub-image is larger only in the upper and left borders, the others remain unchanged. I'm not getting a sub-image with a uniform m pixel thick border around all its sides. This happens for all cases, not just for those on the boundary. Is there any logical error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are modifying the x and y of the rectangle you are not increasing it's size, just moving it, and then you increase the width and the height by just m. I think what you want is to increase it by 2m to have the desired effect.

Comment: rather silly not to have noticed, fixed it a while after posting. thanks anyways.